# How know space disk left WITHOUT root

Tags: linux, debian, disk

I'd like to know if there is a way to get free space disk of a unix (debian) system without root (sudo) and if possible in only one command ?

Comment: What is your research effort? How do you do it *with* root? Have you tried the same command without root? Usually `df` does not require root access.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "disk free space"? There is more than one kind of free space: partition space, file system space, etc. If you only want to know "is there enough disk space in my /home/username directory to download an ISO image file", try "df -h /home/username" (the -h option tells df to output "human readable" size units).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what "free space" are you trying to get.

`df` provides information about free space for mounted filesystems and it doesn't require root:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                             717M     0  717M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                737M     0  737M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                295M  1,3M  294M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/fedora-root               17G   11G  5,4G  67% /
tmpfs                                737M  9,5M  727M   2% /tmp
/dev/sda1                            976M  285M  625M  32% /boot
```

If you want to know how much free/unallocated space is on each disk (space not occupied by partitions), you need to use tools like `parted` or `fdisk` and you need root privileges for that. `lsblk` can help, but it doesn't print free space:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0    1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  100M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0  512B  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   0  100M  0 part
```

But you can assume from its output that `sdb` here has approximately 800 MiB of free space for a new partition.

You can get better picture with UDisks, which also has information about partition layout, GNOME Disks uses this data to display free space on disks:

[image]

UDisks doesn't have a simple way to display this. You'd need to use its [DBus API](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition.html) and calculate the free space yourself.